# Directly link two machines while both are connected to a switch

Tags: networking, routing, network-shares, nas, 10gbit

Let's say I have two machines, both with dual (10Gbit) nics. One is my unraid server that acts as a NAS, among other things, the second is my desktop. Both boxes are connected to a Gbit switch. I can access the NAS via the switch, however both machines have an extra 10 Gbit port that could be put to good use -- the write cache on my server is good enough so that the ethernet connection becomes the bottleneck.

As I understand it -- and mind you, I am relatively new at this, you'd usually assign separate IPs to the separate NICS. However, within the same machine, you could assign the same ip adress for both network interfaces. If I'd do this (assign duplicate ips to both interfaces) and connect them with an ethernet cable (probably cat 5e), would the machines *understand* that the fastest connection between the two is not via the switch? With the result that I can access network shares (on the same ip) over a faster connection...?

This would something like this:

```
+---------------+
|  UNRAID BOX   |
|               |
| NIC 1 | NIC 2 |
+---^---+---+---+
    |       |      +-----------+
    |fast   +----> |Gbit Switch|
    |lane   +----> |           |
    |       |      +-----------+
+---v---+---+---+
| NIC 1 | NIC 2 |
|               |
|Windows 10 BOX |
+---------------+
```

Comment: *would the machines understand that the fastest route between the two is not via the switch?* No. Because there is no separate route to the NAS on your PC. *I can access network shares (on the same ip) over a faster connection...?* Yes. Because of the difference in interfaces metric values.

Comment: @Akina maybe faster 'route' wasn't the correct word, since they're both the same route, technically. I meant route as in: way, i.e. connection in this case. I'll edit my question accordingly. So you're saying this would work, right?

Comment: Your edition changes nothing. The interface (not route!) metric depends of the interface type and its link speed (if not corrected manually, of course). If one interface is connected to the commutator with 1 Gbps and another one to the NAS's NIC with 10 Gbps, the last NIC has lower metric, and it will be used for communication.